# rbind() in mapply() results different output in R

Tags: r

Iam new to R and trying to understand mapply() behaviour.
I have two dataframes k1 and k2.
When I use rbind(k1,k2) it appends k2 at the bottom of k1.
But when I use it along mapply(rbind,k1,k2), it takes 1row from k1 and other from k2 and appends.
Is it possible to append k1 after k2 using mapply().
Can you also explain when is mapply() used in real-time scenario.

```
> k1 <- data.frame(x1 = 1:10, x2 = 11:20)
> k2 <- data.frame(x1= 21:30, x2 = 31:40)
> 
> rbind(k1,k2)
   x1 x2
1   1 11
2   2 12
3   3 13
4   4 14
5   5 15
6   6 16
7   7 17
8   8 18
9   9 19
10 10 20
11 21 31
12 22 32
13 23 33
14 24 34
15 25 35
16 26 36
17 27 37
18 28 38
19 29 39
20 30 40
> mapply(rbind,k1,k2)
      x1 x2
 [1,]  1 11
 [2,] 21 31
 [3,]  2 12
 [4,] 22 32
 [5,]  3 13
 [6,] 23 33
 [7,]  4 14
 [8,] 24 34
 [9,]  5 15
[10,] 25 35
[11,]  6 16
[12,] 26 36
[13,]  7 17
[14,] 27 37
[15,]  8 18
[16,] 28 38
[17,]  9 19
[18,] 29 39
[19,] 10 20
[20,] 30 40
```

I want the output using mapply() function like the first output.

Comment: `rbind(k2, k1)`?

Comment: Mapply and Map are used when you want to apply a function many times. Type `example(mapply)` and `?mapply` for details. In my opinion "give me an example of what this function is good for?" is typically not a good fit for asking here on SO, btw. It's generally a site for concrete programming problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapply` applies the function to the first element of the first input and the first element of the second input, second element of the first input and second element of the second input, etc. So since `k1` and `k2` are both dataframes, `mapply(rbind, k1, k2)` would `rbind` first column of `k1` to first column of `k2`, and so on... It then simplifies the output to a matrix.

If you want to use `mapply` in this fashion, you would want to use the non-simplified version (`mapply(f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`) and supply single element lists, this forces `mapply` to `rbind` the *dataframes* and not simplify the output list:

```
mapply(rbind, list(k1), list(k2), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

This gives you the correct binding, but results in a list of one element.

```
[[1]]
   x1 x2
1   1 11
2   2 12
3   3 13
4   4 14
5   5 15
6   6 16
7   7 17
8   8 18
9   9 19
10 10 20
11 21 31
12 22 32
13 23 33
14 24 34
15 25 35
16 26 36
17 27 37
18 28 38
19 29 39
20 30 40
```

The following would give you the same result as `rbind(k1, k2)`:

```
unlist(mapply(rbind, list(k1), list(k2), SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
```

As noted by @Mako212, `Reduce` and `do.call` might be better tools to use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be misusing `mapply()`

Instead, create a list of the data frames:

```
dfList <- list(k1,k2)
```

And `rbind` using `Reduce` like so:

```
Reduce(rbind, dfList)
```

And another way:

```
do.call("rbind",dfList)
```

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. Can you explain what is the advantage of using mapply() function and in which scenario is it used?

Comment: You use `mapply` when you have a function of two or more variables `function (x,y) {x+y}` and you want to apply that function to a list of x and y values. `mapply(function(x,y){x+y},x=df1$a,y=df1$b)`. `mapply` is iterating through each list, and passing it to `rbind` in your example.